# Trac IK solver type

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, ros-melodic, trac-ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just start trying Trac IK for my humanoid robot project using Python. In the example code, the solver type is "Speed", but there are another solver type ("Distance", "Manipulation1", and "Manipulation2"). What is the difference between this solver type? Which one better to calculate IK for a humanoid robot leg? I just trying with "Speed" mode, but sometimes there is no solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335339/trac-ik-solver-type/) by [eko_rudiawan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36685/eko_rudiawan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the `trac_ik_lib` readme ([here](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/9ef45fd67ede62d389c410720ad3915bb8c1dc8f/trac_ik_lib/README.md)):

> ```
> % The type can be one of the following:
> ```

```
% Speed: returns very quickly the first solution found
% Distance: runs for the full timeout_in_secs, then returns the solution that minimizes SSE from the seed
% Manip1: runs for full timeout, returns solution that maximizes sqrt(det(J*J^T))
% Manip2: runs for full timeout, returns solution that minimizes cond(J) = |J|*|J^-1|
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1